# three.js window resizing behaving differently

Tags: resize, three.js

I resized window height and then width.  The issue is that those are behaving differently.

Here is an example -> [Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/d24nt3b2/)

```
renderer.setSize (window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix ();
```

It would be nice if those were behaving in the same way in both cases.

So I wrote -> [Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jk0a6k6z/)

```
renderer.setSize (window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
var fov = 90;
camera.aspect = aspect;

if (aspect > 1.0) {
    ymax = camera.near * Math.tan (
            THREE.Math.degToRad(fov*0.5));
    ymin = - ymax;
    xmin = ymin * aspect;
    xmax = ymax * aspect;
} else {

    xmax = camera.near * Math.tan (
            THREE.Math.degToRad(fov*0.5));
    xmin = - xmax;
    ymin = xmin / aspect;
    ymax = xmax / aspect;
}

camera.projectionMatrix.makeFrustum( xmin, xmax,
    ymin, ymax, camera.near, camera.far );
```

I do not know if it is working as intended atm, or I did not just understand something, but at least for me the later works better as a default.

So the question is pretty much, did I miss something relevant?  Or is there any interest to have this kind of default behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You missed something relevant.

For a perspective camera, `camera.fov` is always the vertical field of view. So your approach is not acceptable.

three.js r.70

Comment: I understand, makes sense.

I assume that developers might be still interested from this kind of resize behavior, where the specific things are displayed regardless of the window size.